# Python 3 - Calculating the difference between two time values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two values. An expected amount of time that I think an action is going to take, and a value of how long it actually took to complete that task. When searching for a solution I found this code that works fine up until the task took longer to finish than what was expected.

```
Expected = '00:00:20'
Actual = '00:00:25'

FMT = '%H:%M:%S'

Difference = datetime.strptime(Expected, FMT) - datetime.strptime(Actual, FMT)

print(Difference)
```

This prints

```
-1 day, 23:59:55
```

So I was wondering how I can get the result to show up as -00:00:05 instead?

Comment: A workaround could be to calculate the absolute value, and check the signum.

Comment: Did you realise that you're doing Expected - Actual? That could be the problem.

Comment: Theoretically, you could convert everything into seconds and do the calculations manually. There's probably a way to do it without that though.

Comment: `Difference = datetime.strptime(Actual, FMT) - datetime.strptime(Expected, FMT)` then change sign?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do it in 3 steps:

1. step: Compare the 2 time values
2. step: Subtract the smaller one from the bigger one
3. step: If you needed to reverse the order of the numbers in the 2. step, then you have a negative amount of time, otherwise the difference is positive.

EDIT:
The whole code looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
Expected = '00:00:20'
Actual = '00:00:25'

FMT = '%H:%M:%S'

time1=datetime.strptime(Expected, FMT)
time2=datetime.strptime(Actual, FMT)
rev=time1<time2
Difference =  time2 - time1 if rev else time1-time2
print("-" if rev else "",Difference,sep="")
```

Comment: Did you try your steps out yourself?

Comment: Are you kidding, just copy paste the code here: https://repl.it/languages/python3  You will see that it works perfectly, and I don't see the reason of downvoting my answer.

Comment: Now I have added the code to my answer, so please remove the down vote. It works in Python 3, in Python 2 you should make the line print a little bit differently.

Comment: Thanks :) You can just use the website I sent you for testing my code, it's a web based Python 3 interpreter ;)